# Learning database design with EF code first

Tags: database-design, ef-code-first

What **subjects** should be covered in order to grasp a decent knowledge on how to implement a well-structured database model with EF code-first? (assuming no any previous knowledge on SQL\databases exists, but C# and basic EF techniques are known)

References to literature on the required subjects can be helpful.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I honestly don't think you're going to learn anything about database design using code-first.  The fact of the matter is that code-first is for people who don't want to <sarcasm>waste time</sarcasm> doing database design and just want to dive right in and start cutting code.  Good database design is about understanding what information is going to be important to your application and how the storage and retrieval of that information should be structured to make your code flexible and easy to maintain.  That sort of work should be done before coding.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Let me then, correct my question and reduce the learning requirements to the subjects of learning database fundamentals, structures, relationships, and then, the ability to implement a database model via code first only. I realize that pure design aspects requires more than Code First is  about… Tnks again.

Comment: Maybe a little bit more about where my problem comes from: I am very new in the area of developing. I already have stated a first project, after learning some time.
I use code first to structure a not so complicated database, but with time do encounter some series problems related to my model, which I guess are subjects to a very loose knowledge of how should healthy database model be implemented…

Comment: The two most important pieces of advice I would say are learn what "3rd normal form" is and take an object-oriented approach to designing tables.  By this I mean start by making a table for each tangible or abstract thing your system keeps data about.  Think about how you would model your app's reality rather than jumping ahead into thinking about how you would access your data.  The DB and your ORM will worry about access strategies.  If your data model corresponds to the reality that your app works with then you'll probably be on the right track.

Comment: Get yourself a really good book like [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201752840), read through it, apply what you've learned, read it again, reflect on what you've read, and get experience in DB design by doing it (and learning from your mistakes). That's the only way to go, really.

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting tips!

Answer (score 1):

To learn the theory I can recommend the following text:

- An Introduction to Database Systems by C.J.Date, Addison Wesley

Before you even sit down at a keyboard you need to understand Normalisation up to the BCNF. This is covered in part 1 of this book with plenty of examples.

I recommend installing a DBMS such as MySQL on a personal computer of yours to work through some practical examples. This will help you understand how SQL works and how to access and manipulate data in a database system. The examples contained in the following text are fantastic and full of first class industry experience:

- SQL For Smarties by Joe Celko (and all of his other books especially the puzzle books), Morgan Kaufman

In order to learn ADO.NET Entity Framework, i'd start by reading through the text in MSDN and complement it with a recent reference manual on ADO.NET 4.

- Programming Entity Framework by Julia Lerman, O'Reilly